# python markdown headerid extension custom slugify function error

Tags: python, markdown

I tried to parse my markdown files with python-markdown's headerid extension, with my custom slugify function:

```
import markdown

def my_slugify(value, sep):
    return "100"

md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=['headerid(slugify=my_slugify)'])
print md.convert("#Head 1")
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "a.py", line 7, in <module>
    print md.convert("#Head 1")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/markdown/__init__.py", line 296, in convert
    newRoot = treeprocessor.run(root)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/markdown/extensions/headerid.py", line 139, in run
  id = slugify(''.join(itertext(elem)), sep)
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

I looked into headerid's source code. It seems that the headerid extension just use the unicode object as a callable object:

```
id = slugify(''.join(itertext(elem)), sep)
```

So my question is how can I pass my custom slugify function to headerid? Besides, my python version is 2.7.3 and python-markdown is 2.3.1. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the documentation [here](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/reference.html#extensions) and read the headerid codes again, and found the solution:

```
import markdown
from markdown.extensions.headerid import HeaderIdExtension

def my_slugify(value, sep):
    return "100"

md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=[HeaderIdExtension(configs=[('slugify', my_slugify)])])
print md.convert("#Head 1")
```

which gives the correct output:

```
<h1 id="100">Head 1</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed markdown and could do this :

```
import markdown

def my_slugify(value, sep):
    return "100"

extension_config = {'headerid':('slugify','my_slugify')}

md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=extension_config)
print md.convert("#Head 1")
```

which prints

```
<h1 id="head-1">Head 1</h1>
```

this is [in the official doc](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/reference.html#the-basics)

I hope this could help

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have read the documentation and finally found the soluton.

Comment: @wilburma can you tell us what is this one so the next visitor can found it too ? ;)